# Does the supersonic air from a compressor heat things up?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

The air coming from air compressor nozzle is often supersonic which can be observed by the presence of shock diamonds. But is this supersonic air able to heat things up because of air friction? Or if it isn't then why?

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning and welcome to the forum.

Shock waves are a formation of standing wave patterns that appear in the supersonic exhaust plume of a supersonic jet engine, rocket, ramjet, or scramjet, when it is operated in an atmosphere. The diamonds are formed from a complex flow field and are visible due to the abrupt changes in local density and pressure caused by standing shock waves.

Now to answer your question.  Yes, high-velocity air can cause friction which will heat up a surface.  But mainly at the point of contact.   Think of an asteroid streaking through the atmosphere.  The friction from the air causes it to heat up.  Depending on the material the item is made of and the length of time the item is under the high-velocity air will determine how hot the item will get.

Comment: The heat load from friction is minor. Convection is the dominant source of heat transfer in supersonic flow across bodies. The relevant temperature driving the heat flux is called the "recovery temperature" and is roughly 80% the total temperature of the flow (actual proportion varies with flow).

Here's the kicker, for a supersonic vehicle or object, the total temperature increases wildly with Mach number, giving high recovery temps and large heat loads. For a supersonic jet (as made from shop air) the total temperature will be ~ambient, so realistically you will be cooling.